# How to convert a modal pop-up in PDF

Tags: javascript

I have a receipt that is displayed in a pop-up modal.
I want to convert its style (CSS3 and bootstrap) in PDF using JavaScript.
There is a library that I can use to do this?

Comment: I found the solution when I follow this post [How to convert HTML(CSS) To PDF Using JavaScript](http://www.techumber.com/html-to-pdf-conversion-using-javascript/)